# filter out a dictionary within NOT isin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I read a dataframe into a dictionary. Earlier, I was filtering out all the rows which are `.isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])`. This worked correctly

```
df = {}
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = pd.read_sql_table('cgo_eafapo_t', engine, schema_z2,
                                    columns = cols)
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = df['cgo_eafapo_t'][df['cgo_eafapo_t']['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])]
```

However, now I want to filter out all rows which are NOT IN `(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])`. How can I do so? I know we can use a `~` but I am not sure where exactly. I tried this but it threw a Type error:

```
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = ~df['cgo_eafapo_t'][df['cgo_eafapo_t']['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])]
```

```
ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
```

Also tried putting the sign before art_kennz but that  threw an error too

```
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = df['cgo_eafapo_t'][df['cgo_eafapo_t'](~['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4']))]
```

```
attribute error list object has no attribute isin
```

This did not work either:

```
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = df['cgo_eafapo_t']~([df['cgo_eafapo_t']['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `~` before condition:

```
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = df['cgo_eafapo_t'][~df['cgo_eafapo_t']['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4'])]
```

Better is select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = df.loc[~df['cgo_eafapo_t']['art_kennz'].isin(['I1','I2','I3','I4']), 'cgo_eafapo_t']
```